# Grouping data frame by related entities

Tags: r, grouping

I'm having the following data frame, which contains (among other fields) `id` number and `cust` account:

```
 ID  Cust_acc
 1     22
 1     33
 2     33
 3     44
 4     44
 4     55
```

As you can see, one account can have more than one `id` and one `id` can have more than one account.

I'd like to split the data into *related* groups, such that all the related entities will be in one group (the reason is that I want that all *related* `accounts` and `id`'s will be handled in one place).

So in my example, I'd like to get 2 groups:

```
# first
    ID  Cust_acc
     1     22
     1     33
     2     33

# second
    ID  Cust_acc
     3     44
     4     44
     4     55
```

Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: How do you define related?

Comment: as it defined in my example... if you have "one" connection to the group you should be in; i.e., if `id` has 2 `accounts`, they should be in the same group.. and then, if one of the `accounts` has some other `id` he should be in there as well (and so on.. until its done)

Comment: I think this needs igraph

Comment: @akrun I'm working on a closed environment :( ... and it takes long time to add new packages..  
Can you think on some other way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it with just base R, create a grouping variable and then `split`

```
group = 1
for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
    if (df$ID[i] %in% df$ID[1:(i-1)]) {
        group[i] = group[which(df$ID == df$ID[i])[1]]
    }else if (df$Cust_acc[i] %in% df$Cust_acc[1:(i-1)]) {
        group[i] = group[which(df$Cust_acc == df$Cust_acc[i])[1]]
    }else{
        group[i] = max(group) + 1
    }
}

split(df, group)    
#1`
#  ID Cust_acc
#1  1       22
#2  1       33
#3  2       33

#$`2`
#  ID Cust_acc
#4  3       44
#5  4       44
#6  4       55
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

It would be easier to do with `igraph`.  Convert the `data.frame` to `graph` object ('g1'), extract the `membership` from the `clusters`, subset the `names` of the `membership` based on the 'ID' column, create a grouping variable to `split` the original dataset

```
library(igraph)
g1 <- graph.data.frame(df1)
cl <- clusters(g1)$membership
split(df1, cl[names(cl) %in% df1$ID][df1$ID])
$`1`
#  ID Cust_acc
#1  1       22
#2  1       33
#3  2       33

#$`2`
#  ID Cust_acc
#4  3       44
#5  4       44
#6  4       55
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), Cust_acc = c(22L, 
33L, 33L, 44L, 44L, 55L)), .Names = c("ID", "Cust_acc"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Amazing! (I cheked it on my private computer with a sample data frame).. Thank you very much :)

Comment: With your premmision, I'll give my vote to the other answer, because I wrote in a comment that I prefer not to use `igraph`.. Moreover, I'd like to ask you one thing: how does your code knows to take into account only `ID` and `Cust_acc`? i.e., I add another column which share common values with `Cust_acc`, and it didn't affect the grouping of your code. Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: @staove7  It's okay.  I understand your limitations.   If you want only the 'ID' and 'Cust_acc', then subset the dataset i.e. `df2 <- df1[c("ID", "Cust_acc")]` and then apply the code on that

Comment: Hi, sorry to interrupt you... I'm trying to use `igraph` on my data set.. but, when I'm running my code, I'm getting only one group.. I checked the process, and it seems the problem is in `cl[names(cl) %in% df1$ID][df1$ID]` because it gives me `NA`'s.. can you tell me why is that?

Comment: @staove7  I am not sure.  Based on the data in my post, it is working fine for me

Comment: I know.. also on a sample I created.. but, when I'm trying it on my "real" data something gets wrong.. maybe the reason is my data structure or something like that.. I thought you might have any assumption about it

Comment: I loaded it from a `csv`.. do you think it has any connection to it?

Comment: @staove7  Please check the str(yourdata) and compare it with `str(df1)` to see if the class are right.  Also, in `df1`, there was no NA

Comment: I checked it again.. everything seems fine (the type is `dataframe`, the 2 variables are `integers`..) but something is not right. It looks like each part works just fine: `names(cl) %in% df2$Customer_IP` and `cl[names(cl) %in% df2$Customer_IP]` and df2$Customer_IP.. but putting it together: `cl[names(cl) %in% df2$Customer_IP][df2$Customer_IP]` brings me a list of `NA`'s.. any idea?

Comment: @staove7  Okay, it could be because that `df2$Customer_IP` may not be a integer ids like in `df1` or the values are not in sequence?

Comment: `df2$Customer_IP` is `int` type. How can I check (and fix) the _sequence_ thing?

Comment: @staove7  Perhaps `i1 <- with(df2, match(Customer_IP, unique(Customer_IP))); cl[names(cl) %in% df2$Customer_IP][i1]`  Anyway you wanted a non- igraph solution.